# Android error with proguardRelease

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease'. > java.io.IOException: Failed to rename
```

I got the above error when i am generating signed apk, I clean and rebuild the project, then also got the same error,but when i put **minifienabled** false ,its working fine.  I think  problem is with buildtools, gradle version are not compatible. can any one suggest correct config ? some times signed apk was generated and when i install and check ,it crashes suddendly , can anyone please help.

project build.gradle

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.5.0-beta2'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

app build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.kitchenvilla.gingerbuds"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 25
        versionName "1.3.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

android {
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
}
android {
    publishNonDefault true
}


dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.0'
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.15'
    compile 'org.apmem.tools:layouts:1.10@aar'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0'
    compile 'com.pkmmte.view:circularimageview:1.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.3.2'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.7.0'
    compile project(':libs:viewPager')
}
```

Comment: make sure you are using the latest build tools and gradle plugin. Alt+Enter on the lines of the build tools and gradle plugin (in the top build.gradle file, not the app module file) and see if you get a offer to upgrade them.

Comment: I am using latest versions ,any suggestions ?

Comment: Sounds like your missing the proguard rules to protect the lib methods your using.  Please post both the errors shown during build and your `proguard-rules.pro` (hint with proguard its probably a lot of output but the error is in there somewhere, most likely not at the bottom of the output).

Comment: Also having multiple `android` blocks is not going to help you.  Combine the `android` closures into a single closure block

Comment: Yes sir, your are correct, I tried with proguard.pro and gradle versions , finally its worked out. Thank you for your suggestion.